# Loop through weired JSON in Javascript

Tags: jquery, json

I have a PHP script that returns a json encoded result like this:

```
// I added "var jsonp =" manually to make it an array variable.

var jsonp = [
    [
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2012-12-21",
            "phone": "+15879891300",
            "Text": "Hello"
        },
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2013-01-08",
            "phone": "+15879891400",
            "Text": "Issue"
        },
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2013-01-19",
            "phone": "+15879891040",
            "Text": "This is a test "
        }
    ],
    [],
    [
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2013-01-16",
            "phone": "+142610588790",
            "Text": "kkk 1"
        },
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2013-01-18",
            "phone": "+123610588790",
            "Text": "Test 23"
        },
        {
            "txtHide": "N",
            "data": "2013-01-22",
            "phone": "+123610588790",
            "Text": "Hi"
        }
    ],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [
        {
            "txtHide": "Y",
            "data": "2013-01-05",
            "phone": "+221522988655",
            "Text": "oo 12"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I loop through this JSON result using JQuery?

Here is what I did but it prints only the four first lines:

```
$.each(jsonp, function(i,val) {
        console.log(val[i].txtshare);
        console.log(val[i].dtzserver);
        console.log(val[i].txtphonee164);
        console.log(val[i].txtfinding);
    });
```

My Firebug Console outputs :

```
Y
2012-12-21
+15879891300
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3 dimensional array, so you need two loops:

```
$.each(jsonp, function() {
    $.each(this, function () {
        console.log(this.txtshare);
        console.log(this.dtzserver);
        console.log(this.txtphonee164);
        console.log(this.txtfinding);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example "val" refers to the nested array in your main "jsonp" array.  You'd need a nested $.each structure to get the inner contents of the nested array like:

```
$.each(jsonp, function(index, value){
    $.each(value, function(index, innerval){
        console.log(innerval.txtshare);
        //... and so on
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch it's working, you saved the trouble of looking for a fix :) thanks.